# Accessing Collection Variables in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

**Feature**

Postman added support for variables, authorization, pre-request and test scripts to collections.
(As of version 5.4.1 this exists at both the collection AND the folder level.)

**Use case**

Let's say I want to store a refresh token when the login endpoint is hit. My test script needs to create/update a COLLECTION variable, NOT a global or environment variable.

Once that refresh token is available to the collection, other tests and pre-request scripts, I would think there is a way to access them through an API similar to *pm.environment* or *pm.globals*. (pm.collection, for instance)

**Question**

I cannot find any documentation on how to access or modify those via pre-request scripts, or tests... Does anyone know how to do this? Maybe this hasn't been thought out completely, or not fully implemented, but I thought I would check with others for some help.

**Temporary Solution**

As a complete hack, I am storing the things I need as namespaced environment variables. It's not ideal (makes things kind of messy when working in other collections) but it works just fine.

Comment: Have you created an [issue in postman github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues) ?

Comment: I think [issue#4449](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4449) requests this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Postman v7.9.0 added support for new `pm.collectionVariables`, so you can update them on test scripts:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("collection_variable", newValue);
```

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5053#issuecomment-542555156

Comment: For people reading this in 2019+, this is the correct answer.
Postman should create collection variable snippets!

Comment: To _access_ baseUrl use `pm.collectionVariables.get("baseUrl")`.

Comment: I have updated this to the accepted answer (I agree with Kyle's comment above, from October 27, 2019 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman#comment103481675_58507558)

Answer (score 24):

**Collection variables**

You can access collection variables (and all variables) in the pre-request and test script sections using [`pm.variables.get("variableName")`](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference#pmvariables).

However, you can only define and update collection variables by [editing the collection details via modal](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#defining-collection-variables).

***Note:*** For your current solution using environment variables getting messy, remember you can always use `pm.environment.set()` to reset the value or `pm.environment.unset()` to clear it.

Comment: It looks like pm.variables.get() works correctly for what I am trying to accomplish so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

*Setting* collection variables ***manually*** and then *getting* them
was always possible.

*Setting* collection variables ***in scripts*** and not just manually
became possible in version **7.9.0** which was released in October
2019.
As of writing this, there is still obsolete misinformation about it
out there - on the internet in general - but sadly also here
at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Although [this question has already been correctly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58507558), I am adding this answer in an
attempt to clear up any remaining confusion.

#### A collection variable can be *set in a script*

To find out [who is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58507558) and
[who is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028012), I made a simple
little experiment.
Below I describe what I did.
You can replicate the exact same experiment yourself.

I have created a Postman collection named `ManipCollVars`.
(*ManipulateCollectionVariables* seemed a little too long.)
You can download and save it to your local drive from:
https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/postman/ManipCollVars.pm_coll.json.

Then - from your Postman desktop app (not the chrome extension) -
import `ManipCollVars` (*Collections* > *Import* > *File* >
*Upload Files*) as shown in the figure below.
(The dummy GET request is `https://postman-echo.com/get`.)

[image: Import the collection 'ManipCollVars'.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

#### The *initial* value of the collection variable `CollectionVar`

In the left pane, on the same line as `ManipCollVars` is displayed,
click on the ellipsis to the right (the three mini circles: •••), and
then *Edit*.
See the figure below.

[image: Edit the collection properties of 'ManipCollVars'.]

Next click on the *Variables* tab.
Note that the CURRENT VALUE of `CollectionVar` is "Initial Value".

[image: The CURRENT VALUE of CollectionVar equals 'Initial Value'.]

#### Run the dummy request and the *Tests* script

Click on the request `ManipCollVars-Request`, and then on its *Tests*
tab as shown in the figure below.
Focus on lines 7-11:

```js
// Will now try to change `CollectionVar` to some new value:
pm.collectionVariables.set('CollectionVar', 'Some New Value');
// Then print the new value of `CollectionVar` to the console:
console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get('CollectionVar'));
// ^ Does CollectionVar contain "Initial Value" or "Some New Value"? ^
```

Click on the blue <kbd>Send</kbd> button, and then open the *Console*
in the bottom left corner as in the figure below.
Note how the value of the collection variable has changed from
"Initial Value" to "Some New Value". - *Issue settled!*

[image: The value of CollectionVar is now 'Some New Value'.]

#### Double-checking the value of the collection variable

To double-check that the value has indeed changed, click once again on
the ellipsis (•••) next `ManipCollVars` > *Edit* > *Variables*.
Note that the CURRENT VALUE of `CollectionVar` is now
"Some New Value". - **Confirmed!**

[image: The value of CollectionVar has changed to 'Some New Value'.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

#### References

- [Correct answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58507558)
- [Defining variables in scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#defining-variables-in-scripts)
- [Postman Quick Reference Guide: Collection variables](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#collection-variables)
- [Using collection variables in scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-collection-variables-in-scripts)
- [Answer to "Using Collection Variables in Postman"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325002)
- [Postman: The Easy Way to Work with APIs](https://blog.postman.com/postman-the-easy-way-to-work-with-apis/)