# Postman programmatically set collection variables in pre-request script

Tags: postman

Currently, it is possible to set and get variables from the `global` and `environment` scope, as well as the generic `variable` in a pre-request script.  However, the documentation is not clear if it is possible to programmaticaly set `collection` scoped variables.

For example

```
pm.environment.set("timestamp", timestamp);  //acceptable
pm.global.set("signature", hash);  //acceptable
pm.variable.set("signature", hash); //acceptable
pm.collection.set("signature", hash); //not possible?
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Collection Variables in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can only currently set these manually at the Collection level but you can reference these using the `pm.variables.get('var_name')` syntax.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#defining-collection-variables

EDIT:

Postman now allows you to use:

`pm.collectionVariables.set('var_name', 'var_value')` and `pm.collectionVariables.get('var_name')` to interact with the Variables at the Collection level.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325002/6028443

Comment: Programmatically setting the Collection level variables will be part of the app very soon. Should added around `7.9.0` so be on the look out for it. 

Comment: For those landing here from Google, `pm.collectionVariables` is what I needed.  See the StackOverflow linked in the edit above.  At the time of posting this comment, there appears to be little-to-no documentation on the new API.