# Using Collection Variables in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection

All the examples on [learning.getpostman.com](https://learning.getpostman.com) site show how to save variables at the `global` or `environment` level, in order to get a value from one request to another.

For example:

```js
pm.environment.set(variableName:String, variableValue:String)
pm.environment.get(variableName:String)

pm.globals.set(variableName:String, variableValue:String) 
pm.globals.get(variableName:String)
```

respectively.

Is it possible to use Collections instead?

Reading the [documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/#pmvariables) about the `pm.` API doesn't give me much hope.

I am looking for something like this:

```js
pm.collection.set(variableName:String, variableValue:String)
pm.collection.get(variableName:String)
```

My goal is to be able to run two collections without cross-contamination.

### EDIT

Postman evolves. If you [read the documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#defining-variables-in-scripts) it is also possible to set the variables in the collection, instead of in the environment. Be aware that if you have variables with the same name set in both places, using `{{variablename}}` may not result in the desired outcome.
For example, if a collection variable and an environment variable have
the exact same names, they are still two completely different variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Collection Variables in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman)

Comment: @Henke I have edited my edit to clarify the sentence

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Postman version (7.9.0) and beyond, ships with a `pm.collectionVariables` function, this gives users more control over the way that they interact with Variables, at the Collection level.

Previously, you could only manually add these variables and then access them in the sandbox environment using the `pm.variables.get("var_name")` function.

The new `pm.collectionVariables` API method comes with the follows functions:

```js
     .get("var_name")
     .set("var_name", "var_value")
     .has("var_name")
     .unset("var_name")
     .clear()
     .toObject()
```

An example of the syntax would be this:

```js
pm.collectionVariables.set("collectionVariable", "My Awesome New Collection Level Variable");
```

This is a *basic* example of setting a Collection level Variable from the `Tests` tab:

[image: Collection Variables]

Comment: I Must try that.

Answer (score 1):

Update Your **Variables**.

And Then Update Your **Pre-request script**

```js
const tokenUrl = 'http://localhost/api/login';
const email = 'admin@gmail.com';
const password = '12345678';

const getTokenRequest = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: tokenUrl,
    body: {
      mode: 'formdata',
      formdata: [
          { key: 'email', value: email },
          { key: 'password', value: password }
      ]
  }
};

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
  const jsonResponse = response.json();
  const newAccessToken = jsonResponse.data.token;
  let token = pm.collectionVariables.get("token");
  pm.collectionVariables.set('token',newAccessToken);
});
```

Comment: this looks like it is an answer to a completely different question

Comment: its a complete answer of multiple different questions(Including this question). @JoSSte