# How to add collection variables in Postman?

Tags: postman

It says in [postman doc](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#defining-collection-variables) that

> Collection variables can be defined by editing the collection details. Click on the ellipsis (…) next to the collection name, and select “Edit” to open the EDIT COLLECTION modal. Select the Variables tab to add and edit collection variables. You can also define collection variables when creating the collection.

The problem is that when I go to edit collection dialog, there is no Variables tab.

[image]

How can I add variables to collection in Postman?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the desktop app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Collection Variables in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Danny realized that I was using older version of Postman.