# How to change Postman current variable value in collection scope?

Tags: postman

I have variable "TOKEN" in my **collection scope**. I try to set the value using Tests scripts when do a request. But the variable not changed.

So, I try to use **environment scope** variable. And It works.

Why It's doesn't work when in **collection scope**? I had read about postman variable scope [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/) and understand it well.

Here're some screenshots:

**1. First, I call login endpoint.**

[image: Call Login]

Below is the console result. Nothing wrong.

[image: Console Result]

Until I try to get all users endpoint that required token in request header. The status is 401 because the token is null. If the token is not null, then it will return 200:

[image: Get Users Endpoint]

It's gracefully working when I add "TOKEN" variable to environment. Switch to *No Environment* again will result 401 status code:

[image: Result]

Comment: Please add the code you're using and some screen shots, to help explain what you're doing. Currently, it says "I have this thing I'm not showing you and I have this code doing something you can't see" :) You need to provide more context for people to help.

Comment: Okay, I had add it recently. @DannyDainton

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically set the variable at the collection level? You will only be able to read or get those and not write or set them.

Comment: @DannyDainton Okay. I think it's good to explain in postman's page about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Collection Variables in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman)

Comment: It took some time, but I have now written the answer I set out to do - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65942023.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be new since this question was posted, but for anyone else
finding this, you can set collection variables using:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set(key, value)
```

See:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#defining-variables-in-scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can now use:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

- In my original answer in June 2019, I wrote that collection variables are not editable through scripts, and can only be changed manually. As noted, this is no longer the case. . . .*

Comment: @Henke https://assets.postman.com/postman-docs/Variables-Chart.png
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

This is what it says on the postman docs, if it changed over the years then maybe they added a new way of doing it. But this was the status of june 2019

You now can indeed use: pm.collectionVariables.set("variable_key", "variable_value");

Comment: Since you have updated your answer, I removed my two comments which
 did not make much sense any more. In your current answer, you might want to
 replace everything below the horizontal line with something like:
_In my original answer in June 2019, I wrote that collection variables are not
 editable through scripts, and can only be changed manually.
As noted, this is no longer the case._ . . .
You might also want to take a look at
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655 and
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `Automatic persist variable values` from postman settings.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSSsX.jpg)

Comment: This is not exactly an anwer to the question but was useful for me anyway. :) This solves the problem with `pm.environment.set` setting both `current` and `initial` variable values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only set env variables when some environment is selected: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox/#environment-and-global-variables

[image]

Comment: The question concerns **_collection_** variables, not **_environment_** variables.