# Postman Get Current Collection Variable Value

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I need to get current exact collection variable value.

In pre-request script of a postman request I'm setting **2 collection variables** as follows

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("firstCollectionVariable", "string_{{$guid}}");
pm.collectionVariables.set("secondCollectionVariable", "second_variable_{{firstCollectionVariable}}");
```

then I'm using those 2 collection variables in a post request body to set specific data as follows

```
 { 
    "firstKey": {{firstCollectionVariable}},
    "secondKey" : {{secondCollectionVariable}},
 }
```

firstKey and secondKey are set as expected

firstKey => "string_c6631d2c-2427-4903-b604-8120662a5e0e"

secondKey => "second_variable_string_c6631d2c-2427-4903-b604-8120662a5e0e"

The problem is when I'm trying to check the response using

```
pm.expect(pm.response.secondKey).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get("secondCollectionVariable"));
```

I got assertion error

> AssertionError: expected
> 'second_variable_string_c6631d2c-2427-4903-b604-8120662a5e0e' to
> deeply equal 'second_variable_{{firstCollectionVariable}}'

How I can get the current exact value of collection variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Collection Variables in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680580/accessing-collection-variables-in-postman)

Answer (score 1):

maybe using `to.be.deep` can solve your problem, try something like:

```
pm.expect(pm.response.secondKey).to.be.deep.equals(pm.collectionVariables.get("secondCollectionVariable"));
```

or

```
pm.expect(pm.response.secondKey).to.be.deep.equal(pm.collectionVariables.get("secondCollectionVariable"));
```

Another nice shot can be just use single quotes to get your collectionVariable like `'secondCollectionVariable'`

I hope this works for you, best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Converting your variables to string might also solve your problem.